# Is there a library similar to Orekit in .NET?

Tags: java, .net, astronomy

I would like to know if a library similar to [Orekit](http://www.orekit.org/) exists in .NET.

I am curremtly trying to use [OrbitTools](http://www.zeptomoby.com/satellites/) but it lacks decent documentation.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late for an answer. But you can easily use orekit from .NET by translating the jar file to a .NET .dll using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/)

I tried this a while ago and did some simple kepler propagation, and I did not have any problems.

Here are a few more instructions:

IKVM is a fully functional JVM that runs on the CLR. Since both platforms are very similar this can be pretty fast (almost as fast as a native .NET)

To use a java library from .NET you first have to compile it to a managed code .dll. The program in the IKVM distribution to do this is called ikvmc.

If your .jar has dependencies to other .jars outside the java standard library, you have to translate these as well and add them to the visual studio project.

Orekit only has a dependency on apache.commons.math, a vector library from apache. So this is the command line:

```
> ikvmc orekit-5.0.3.jar commons-math-2.1.jar
Note IKVMC0002: output file is "orekit-5.0.3.dll"
```

Now you have orekit-5.0.3.dll in the same directory. You can add this to visual studio just like any other .dll, but you have to add some additional .dlls for the IKVM runtime. Refer to IKVM documentation for which .dlls you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the ASCOM platform, release 5.5.1 has a .NET wrapper around the NOVAS vector astrometry routines and also the Keppler orbit engine. http://ascom-standards.org